# Django storages and django pipeline - upload only compressed static files

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, storage, asset-pipeline

I am trying to combine django pipeline and django-storages to automatically upload only compressed files to amazon s3.

It's failing all the time. It's uploading all possible files or it's uploading empty files or even I am gettings errors when CachedFileFinder is enabled.

I am kinda stuck and don't know what to do at this point.

custom_storages.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin, PipelineCachedStorage
from storages.backends.s3 import S3Storage
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.webdesign',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    # External libs
    'storages',
    'pipeline',
    'endless_pagination',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'mptt',
    'south',
    #'debug_toolbar',
    'rest_framework',
    'memcache_status',
    'parsley',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_forms_foundation',

    # Apps
    'core',
    'adverts',
    'places',
    'images',
    'categories',
)


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.core_storage.S3PipelineStorage'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'pipeline.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    #'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
)


PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'base': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'css/style.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/core.css',
    },

}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'base': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js',
            'foundation/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js',
            'foundation/js/app.js',
            'js/jquery.wookmark.js',
            'js/libs/endless-pagination.js',
            'js/libs/jquery.autosize-min.js',
            'js/libs/global.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/jquery.js',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors with `CachedFileFinder` is pretty normal, especially if using 3rd party CSS, because it tries to parse the CSS `@include` statements and transform the URLS to cached versions. You have to be really careful about the formatting of CSS includes.

Django also needs to upload all the files, even the uncompressed ones, because they still may be referenced by their non-cached names in places. Theoretically you could get rid of this restriction, but it would likely be easier just to live with it.